# convert bash code to generate sh1 into python code to do the same

Tags: python, bash

i'm using the following code to generate sh1 via bash

```
gen_sh1="api_format=$api_format&api_key=$api_key&api_nonce=$api_nonce&api_timestamp=$api_timestamp&custom.videoId="$customvideoId"&description=$description&downloadurl=$sourceurl&duration=$duration&sourceformat=$sourceformat&sourcetype=$sourcetype&sourceurl=$sourceurl&title="$description"GKxS7otlAsujiRxXHTvshUE9"
```

then

```
api_signature=`echo -n $gen_sh1 | sha1sum | awk '{print $1}'`
```

to catch the value ,

what is the equivalent in python to generate the same sh1 with parameters i'm passing  and catch  the value

please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import the **hashlib** module that is included with Python, and do something like this:

```
import hashlib


# Assuming all arguments to format have been defined above...
gen_sh1 = "api_format={}&api_key={}&api_nonce={}&api_timestamp={}&custom.videoId={}&description={}&downloadurl={}&duration={}&sourceformat={}&sourcetype={}&sourceurl={}&title={}GKxS7otlAsujiRxXHTvshUE9".format(
    api_format,
    api_key, 
    api_nonce,
    api_timestamp,
    customvideoId,
    description,
    sourceurl,
    duration,
    source_format,
    sourcetype,
    sourceurl, 
    description) 

api_signature = hashlib.sha1(gen_sh1).hexdigest()

print api_signature
```

Comment: gen_sh1 = "api_format=" + api_format + "&api_key=" + api_key + "&api_nonce=" + api_nonce + "&api_timestamp=" + api_timestamp + "&custom.videoId=" + customvideoId + "&description=" + description + "&downloadurl=" + sourceurl + "&duration=" + duration "&sourceformat=" + sourceformat + "&sourcetype=" + sourcetype + "&sourceurl=" + sourceurl + "&title="+ description + "GKxS7otlAsujiRxXHTvshUE9"   i modified it and start getting  TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: all my params are mixed numbers / text and ursl   so i start getting TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Try enclosing the other types in str() ... For example if you try concatenating "api_format=" + 44 + "&api_key" you will get the TypeError. Then you just do "api_format=" + str(44) + "&api_key" and all is good. Of course instead of the hardcoded 44 you could just have an integer variable in that place

Comment: No problem ;-).

Comment: The edit from chepner to my answer now, might help you sort things up! I initially thought you had everything hardcoded beside customvideoId and description

Comment: thats pretty good , i've one more small issue here , the title is arabic text when i  use this values to do post requets it failed  bcs arabic text converted to title=\u0627\u0644\u0648\u0648\u0648`"   any idea how to avoid this its should utf-8 unicode

Comment: I would write it as format_str.format(*map(str, [api_format, api_key ... ]))